# Echo last 10 results of mysql database using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to echo the last 10 items in my database with pdo. However I keep getting Query failed. However when I do the code snippet at the very bottom I can get just the very last item in my database.

```
$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name_uroll, $db_username, $db_password);

$statement2 = $db2->prepare("select * from `{$user}` ORDER BY bet_id DESC LIMIT 2");    


if ($stmt = $db2->query($statement2)) //PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement on success or false on failure.
{
    //If we got a PDOStatement as a return value from PDO::Query() !!!ECHO WHILE FETCHING!!! 
    while($row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //This loop will keep going for as many rows as the PDOStatement returns.
    {
        echo $row2['roll'] . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    //If PDO::Query returned false, then something is wrong with our query. Or connection or whatever.
     echo "Query failed.";
}
```

But when I do this below it works, but only prints out the very last item

```
$row2 = $statement2->fetch();
echo $row2[roll];
```

Comment: If you're preparing your statement you should be using `db2->execute()`, not `db2->query()`, but since you're not actually binding any variables you could just feed your query string into `db2->query()`. I think you need to read more on PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: you want to `echo the last 10` but you have `LIMIT 2` in you query?

Comment: @Sean I plan on doing 10 I just put 2 to test some things out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove prepare statement. and run query directly inside query function.

```
    $db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name_uroll, $db_username, $db_password);

//Remove $db2 prepare
$statement2 = "select * from `{$user}` ORDER BY bet_id DESC LIMIT 2";    


if ($stmt = $db2->query($statement2)) //PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement on success or false on failure.
{
    //If we got a PDOStatement as a return value from PDO::Query() !!!ECHO WHILE FETCHING!!! 
    while($row2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) //This loop will keep going for as many rows as the PDOStatement returns.
    {
        echo $row2['roll'] . "<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    //If PDO::Query returned false, then something is wrong with our query. Or connection or whatever.
     echo "Query failed.";
}
```

This code is working.

Docs link: http://www.php.net/pdo.query

Using prepare you have to use execute method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: have you removed the prepare statement? and running you query inside query function?
Can you echo or print your query?

Comment: please cecho inside if statement. if ($stmt // so you can see if control is atleast coming inside if.

Comment: Yeah I copied and pasted the above code too just in case. $statement2 works but echoing $stmt gives nothing.

Comment: sorry i did not get you point. echoing $stmt????. echo $statement2 here and then run this query inside phpmyadmin. if runs ok then echo inside while loop. anything echo 'hello'. if any error let me know.

Comment: echo $statement2 works fine. When I echo in while loop nothing gets printed. When I echo inside the if statement nothing gets printed either.

Comment: hmmm...this code is running ok with me. please can you run this query inside phpmyadmin and see what it returns. if query runs ok then there is some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is tested code.

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "pdo";
$dbuser = "root";

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser);
echo $select = "SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = $con->prepare($select);
$query->execute();
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<pre>';print_r($row);echo '</pre>';
}
```

or you can do like this

```
if($query->execute()) {
   $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
   while($row = $query->fetch()) {
       echo '<pre>';print_r($row);echo '</pre>';
   }
} else {
    echo "Query failed";
}
```

Comment: Tried the first and got nothing. Added in the second part and I still get Query failed.

Comment: $db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$db_name_uroll, $db_username, $db_password); This is your code and this is my code $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser); remove the single quote from $host varibale and $db_name_uroll then check.

Comment: and what is `{$user}` in select query this should be table name.

Comment: echo your query it'll be printed at browser then copy it and paste it to sqlyog and try to execute it see what happend.